# Scrape everything between two timestamps in log output in terminal

Tags: bash

I have a log output in terminal that has such format:

```
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.609802 Disable FCAM CAM2_SHUTDOWN=0
ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
free heap size=7061506
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU:  CmdTurnOffDevicePower Start: TS: 662.611755 bitfield: 0x3000018
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.611755 Disable JULIET_SHUTDOWN=0
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: [ISP] Destroy Session
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: free heap size=7061506
Statistics: NonPersistentMemory:151650304
AppleH10CamIn::drainIOProcessorChannelMessageQueues - Received 1 messages
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: AppleH10CamIn::drainIOProcessorChannelMessageQueues - Received 1 messages on channel IO after Suspend is completed
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: AppleH10CamIn::ISP_Suspend - Succeeded! (didDeInit=No!)
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: AppleH10CamIn::ISP_Suspend - Statistics: Starts:2, Resumes:3967, SuspendSuccesses:3969, SuspendFails:0, ResumeFails:0, DeInits:1
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: AppleH10CamIn::ISP_Suspend - Statistics: NonPersistentMemory:151650304, PersistentMemory:29858287, DeletionPendingMemory:0, NonPersistentMemoryMax:577929216, PersistentMemoryMax:29858287
```

Basically, I want to **scrape** everything for any particular log that contains an interesting keyword, let's say `ISPCPU:`, between two consecutive timestamp lines (for example `Jul 26 00:12:32` to the next line of `Jul 26 00:12:32`.  They're not necessarily the same timestamp value. The point is they're just an indicator for the starting and ending point of the interesting log. In the real example, the timestamps will change. A generic syntax that matches the timestamp format is much preferable instead of hardcoded timestamps). So the expected output would be:

```
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.609802 Disable FCAM CAM2_SHUTDOWN=0
ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
free heap size=7061506
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU:  CmdTurnOffDevicePower Start: TS: 662.611755 bitfield: 0x3000018
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.611755 Disable JULIET_SHUTDOWN=0
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: [ISP] Destroy Session
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: free heap size=7061506
Statistics: NonPersistentMemory:151650304
AppleH10CamIn::drainIOProcessorChannelMessageQueues - Received 1 messages
```

I've been trying to use this, but they only **scrape** the first line:

```
echo "$log_above" | grep "ISPCPU:"
```

In real case `echo "$log_above"` is stdout in the terminal from `oslog`, so it would be something similar to (hence why generic syntax for matching timestamps is preferable):

```
oslog | grep "ISPCPU:"
```

Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: The date format makes the analysis hard — if you have an option, use YYYY-MM-DD format for the date (following ISO 8601).  You can then use simple lexicographical analysis for the range of dates (`date > min_date && date < max_date`, taking care to handle equality properly in both cases — the test shown excludes the end points).  If you can't change the input format, you may still do best by writing code to convert the input values to the suggested format.  Otherwise, you can just convert the sequence of month abbreviations MMM appropriately to MM and then do the lexicographical comparisons.

Comment: Use Perl, Python or Awk to do the work — you probably shouldn't use `grep` at all The suggested programs can all filter for lines containing `ISPCPU` easily, as well as managing the date comparisons.

Comment: the output was from `oslog`, and unfortunately AFAIK there's no way to change the date format. Regarding the lexicographical analysis I think can't really applied here, since one line to another line might have the same date and time, as seen in the first five lines and another next five lines. Yeah I think `awk` might do the job, but I'm really don't know how to utilize them.

Comment: Will your date ranges ever cross day boundaries (say "Jul 26 23:59:30" to "Jul 27 00:00:29")?  What about month boundaries?  What about year boundaries?  Would you ever need to scan across time spans of more than one year?  (I note that if you need to scan across time spans of more than one year, the data format is "useless" — or at least, ambiguous. You can't tell which year any given line of data is relevant to given the information shown.  The logging format leaves a lot to be desired, as already mentioned.)

Comment: They likely will, the timestamp is actually the date in real time when `oslog` is running. You're right about them being ambiguous though, since I'm trying to extract the printed log (which each "log" begins with a timestamp) that contains the particular keyword, and they tends to span across multilines. My first intuitive was to extract everything between two timestamps that contains the keyword, since they indicate they're of the same "log".

Comment: based on the sample input and desired output it appears what you want is **1)** all lines that contain the string `IPSCPU` and **2)** any non-timestamped lines that follow immediately after a line containing `IPSCPU`; if this is the case then all comments/mentions of timestamps, `same or different` (???), could be removed which in turn would alleviate a lot of confusion

Comment: Why is the first `26 Jul 00:12:33` block included in the desired results if the time range is `00:12:32` to `00:12:32`?  Or is it included because the range was bigger and it included the magic word `ISPCPU`?  Your question isn't clear on a number of details that matter.

Comment: I think at this point it's safe to say that markp-fuso explained everything clearly, and the timestamp value is not relevant, it's just an indicator of the starting point and ending point for where the log should be scraped if it contains interested keyword (in this case `ISPCPU:`).

Comment: @Ryan — it was not clear that you were not filtering on a time range but that the times simply marked the start of new records.  Now it is clearer — and the problem is considerably simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put zero byte between message boundaries. Then grep a zero separated stream. Then remove zero bytes. Match the beginning of the message with some regex.

```
sed -E '1!s/^[A-Z][a-z]* [0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [^ ]* [^ ]* <[a-zA-Z]*>: /\x00&/' |
grep -azZ 'ISPCPU:' |
tr -d '\0'
```

Comment: This is genius by adding the zero bytes! It works as expected! One question if you don't mind, if I were to match a colored output, is `tr -d '\0'` still needed? I noticed that it broke when trying to match a colored output: `grep -azZ '\[0;30;46mISPCPU:' | tr -d '\0'`, removing them however works.

Comment: *however works partially (some irrelevant log being scraped too).

Comment: `to match a colored output, is tr -d '\0' still needed?` `sed` adds zero bytes. The `tr` removes them from the output - otherwise they will be there in the output. It's unrelated to color  codes. `I noticed that it broke when trying to match a colored outpu` It's not `\[` (two characters "\" and `[`) but it's a _single  byte_ of value `0x1b` in hex. You can use ANSI quoting in bash `$'\x1b'` or popular to use `$'\033'` to print ESC code. See Wikipedia about ANSI escape codes. There is a thread on stackoverflow about how to match color sequences.

Comment: `some irrelevant log being scraped too` I have written the regex `^[A-Z][a-z]* [0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [^ ]* [^ ]* <[a-zA-Z]*>`  in 1 minute. Write a better one to match the beginning of the line. See [sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). You can learn regex fast and fun with regex crosswords online.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried with `oslog --debug | grep $'\033\[0;30;46mISPCPU:\033\[m'` and it seems to capture well, however when assembled it back to the syntax as answered: `... | grep -azZ '\033\[0;30;46mISPCPU:\033\[m' | tr -d '\0'`, it seems to not output anything. Is it because of the `-z` flag? I don't quite understand this bit, does it split all the color code sequences too with the `z` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single-process solution using Awk.

#### `script.awk`

```sh
/^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] / {
    if (old != "") { print old; old = "" }
    if ($0 ~ /ISPCPU:/)
    {
        if (old == "") old = $0
        else old = old "\n" $0
    }
    next
}
{ if (old != "") old = old "\n" $0 }
END { if (old != "") print old }
```

Given your data in a file `data`, it produces:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.609802 Disable FCAM CAM2_SHUTDOWN=0
ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
free heap size=7061506
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU:  CmdTurnOffDevicePower Start: TS: 662.611755 bitfield: 0x3000018
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: CmdTurnOffDevicePower: TS: 662.611755 Disable JULIET_SHUTDOWN=0
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: ch 0 Blank Extrinsic Cal data
Jul 26 00:12:32 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: [ISP] Destroy Session
Jul 26 00:12:33 mac kernel_task[0] <Notice>: ISPCPU: free heap size=7061506
Statistics: NonPersistentMemory:151650304
AppleH10CamIn::drainIOProcessorChannelMessageQueues - Received 1 messages
```

Managing `old` is the key to this solution.  You can make the date matching regex more or less stringent as suits your needs — it clearly isn't internationalized.

Comment: Wish I could upvote but I'm not qualified, really appreciate the conversation that we had to eventually had my answer (my bad on not explaining the question more clearly in causing any confusion), so thanks so much! This works pretty well with capturing color codes sequence too!